# How can I set environment variables PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Unix TeamCity build agent?

Tags: c++, unix, teamcity, teamcity-5.0

I use TeamCity to build c++ on Unix (Solaris).  TeamCity invokes make, and within my makefile I need to call `svn`.  For this I need to modify `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I could set these within the makefile but the locations vary from server to server.  does anyone know a way to set these for each TeamCity build agent, e.g. by editing  `conf/buildAgent.properties`?

I could set them in `~/.login` etc for the TeamCity build account, but I would prefer not to as it is a shared account.

-thanks, Barney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a wrapper script that exports these variables before executing the TeamCity command.

Comment: Yes I think this is the only option - I was hoping for per-server config in the per-server config file, but this works.

Answer (score 19):

You can configure the environment in `conf/buildAgent.properties` as you suspected, by setting properties that begin with `env.`. It works for both setting variables from scratch and modifying existing values. Mine looks like this:

```
env.MAKEFLAGS=-j8
env.PATH=/usr/local/bin:%env.PATH%
```

(It's [hidden in the docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Project+and+Agent+Level+Build+Parameters). I'm not sure if 5.0 had this (I *think* it did, though), but 7.0 definitely does.)